How to apply multiple conditions when using %in%?
I have this example where I wish to create the column m where if x1 or x2 or x3 = "A" or "B" then m = 1, otherwise m = 0
df <- data.frame(x1 = LETTERS[1:10], x2 = LETTERS[2:11], x3 = LETTERS[3:12])


df <-  df%>% 
   mutate(m = ifelse(df[,paste0("x",1:3)] %in% c("A","B") ,1,0))


when using this code it is not working and I don't know where the bug is and how to fix it. Thanks.

%in%, in this case, won't work, unless you apply the functino to every column: sapply(df, \(x) +x %in% c("A","B"))

Thank you. and to precise that I want only these three columns (in case I have a bigger dataframe but I want to only use these three columns) ?

I would suggest using the case_when function instead of ifelse. Then you can specify the x %in% c('A', 'B') ~ 1 statement for all variables from x1 to x3, and then use .default = 0 to set the value to zero otherwise

Thank you. would you mind writing the code with case_when since I never used this function before

i tried using case_when but I am having the same problem when using %in%. It does not work

df %>% rowwise() %>%  mutate(m = case_when(any(c(x1,x2,x3) %in% c("A","B"))~1, .default=0))

Now I have another problem : I have so many columns and instead of x1,x2,x3 : I wish to use paste0 but with this code it is not working. how to handle it with paste0 ?

You can use rowSums. Better use grep instead of the paste approach.
> df |> 
+   transform(m=+(rowSums(sapply(df[grep('^x\\d$', names(df))], `%in%`, c('A', 'B'))) > 0))
   x1 x2 x3 m
1   A  B  C 1
2   B  C  D 1
3   C  D  E 0
4   D  E  F 0
5   E  F  G 0
6   F  G  H 0
7   G  H  I 0
8   H  I  J 0
9   I  J  K 0
10  J  K  L 0

dplyr::mutate should also work, haven't installed it. Avoid ifelse or the like whenever possible, it's just slow.

Sometimes you can take advantage of the particular structure of your data. If you are looking for A and B among only upper case A-Z you could do:
cols <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")

df$m <- as.integer(do.call(pmin, df[cols]) < "C")

   x1 x2 x3 m
1   A  B  C 1
2   B  C  D 1
3   C  D  E 0
4   D  E  F 0
5   E  F  G 0
6   F  G  H 0
7   G  H  I 0
8   H  I  J 0
9   I  J  K 0
10  J  K  L 0


Don't need rowwisely check, you can try
df$m <- +(rowMeans(`dim<-`(as.matrix(df) %in% c("A", "B"), dim(df))) > 0)

or
df$m <- +(rowMeans(`dim<-`(unlist(df, FALSE, FALSE) %in% c("A", "B"), dim(df))) > 0)

and you will obtain
> df
   x1 x2 x3 m
1   A  B  C 1
2   B  C  D 1
3   C  D  E 0
4   D  E  F 0
5   E  F  G 0
6   F  G  H 0
7   G  H  I 0
8   H  I  J 0
9   I  J  K 0
10  J  K  L 0


Wouldn't unlist() be much faster than as.matrix()?

yes, it is faster @s_baldur

For those of us who forgot :-) ,  worth mentioning that +(stuff) coerces logical values to numeric.

Here's a purrr::map take (three variations) with selection helpers, so you can have more columns with complex names:
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data
df <- data.frame(x1 = LETTERS[1:10], x2 = LETTERS[2:11], x3 = LETTERS[3:12])

# Just helpers
aux <- c("A", "B")
fn  <- \(x, y) any(x %in% y)

# Option 1 A `pmap`
df$m <- pmap_int(
  select(df, starts_with("x")), 
  \(...) some(list(...), \(x) fn(aux, x)))

# Option 2 `mutate` and `pmap`
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(n = pmap_int(
    select(., starts_with("x")), 
    \(...) some(list(...), \(x) fn(aux, x))))

# Option 3: rowwise, `mutate` and `map`
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(o = map_int(
    list(c_across(starts_with("x"))),
    \(x) fn(aux, x))) %>% 
  ungroup() # Always ungroup it after a `rowwise` operation 

The output:
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   x1    x2    x3        m     n     o
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
 1 A     B     C         1     1     1
 2 B     C     D         1     1     1
 3 C     D     E         0     0     0
 4 D     E     F         0     0     0
 5 E     F     G         0     0     0
 6 F     G     H         0     0     0
 7 G     H     I         0     0     0
 8 H     I     J         0     0     0
 9 I     J     K         0     0     0
10 J     K     L         0     0     0

Created on 2024-05-17 with reprex v2.1.0
